# how to use entity to recive the type of neo4j relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
cql1:MATCH(A:SYSTEM{NAME:'HR'})-[R]-(B:SYSTEM{NAME:'ERP'})RETURN  type(R)

cql2:MATCH(A:SYSTEM{NAME:'HR'})-[R]-(B:SYSTEM{NAME:'ERP'})RETURN startNode(R),endNode(R),R

cql3:MATCH(A:SYSTEM{NAME:'HR'})-[R]-(B:SYSTEM{NAME:'ERP'})RETURN startNode(R),endNode(R),R,type(R)
```

cql1：I can package it in List ,and the cq2,I can use a RelationshipEntity to pack;
but cql3,I try to get the type of relationship ,it fail;and said:Unable to find property: type(R);
my entity like that

```
    @Relationship(type = "T_OUT")
    private OUTBasis outBasis ;//pack  startNode(R),endNode(R),R
    @Property
    private String relationType ;//pack type(R)
```

so，how can i recive the cql3 result by the entity ?

Comment: This is just a guess but try adding `type(R) as type_r` to cql3 and change the annotation to `@Property(name="type_r")` and see if that works

Comment: it work @hoyski thank you !

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear